# How to address Eureka Server in Eureka Client on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka

How do you address the Eureka Server on AWS ECS?

### My requirements/current setup

- Eureka Server Deployed as ECS Service with Launch Type EC2

  - Service Discovery (from ECS) enabled, which creates a Route53 DNS entry for the Eureka Server (e.g. eureka.local)
- Eureka Server is only
  for mid-tier Services, hence no external address of Eureka Server
  needed/wanted
- Eureka Server deployed in multiple AZs in one region
- Eureka Client needs to address the Eureka Server
- I would like to use the built into Eureka features like AWS-Zone affinity, which means I want to have a Eureka client talk to the Eureka Server in its own AZ first and only fall back to another AZ's Eureka Server when the one in it's own AZ is not available.

### Addressing via DNS from Route53

When I set the eurekaServerDNSName property, then I get the following exception, because it can't find the txt record for the DNS entry. Is there a way to create the TXT record also and if yes, how shall I set this for ECS Service Discovery?

```
eurekaServerDNSName: service-registry.local
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!

ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver : Resolving eureka endpoints via DNS: txt.eu-west-1.service-registry.local
```

In addition when I want to create the txt record in Route53 for my services, I get the error message that I can't actually change this record, like "The resource hostedzone/yyy can only be managed through servicediscovery.amazonaws.com". So I wonder how I could use DNS configuration with AWS ECS for Eureka configuration.

### Elastic IPs as an alternative

Since Elastic IPs (EIP) expose a public IP this is no possible solution for us.